# How to load ffprobe when deploying in streamlit

Tags: streamlit, ffprobe

I am deploying streamlit app from my github repo. In my app.py ffprobe is required to run. When running locally I installed it and kept in my local directory. But the ffprobe.exe is 493MB hence I cannot upload it to GitHub site. Is there any way i can access ffprobe in my streamlit deployment. I tried adding ffprobe,ffmpeg in my reqirements.txt but it doesn't work.
My local version works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly, putting package names in `packages.txt` will allow the underlying Linux server to install it.

The following Docs page provides further information on other methods of installing App dependencies:

https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-community-cloud/get-started/deploy-an-app/app-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer to this question. I have to add packages.txt in my main repo and inside that add the following:

```
ffmpeg
```